# Calling a method which executes delegate methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

I have a view controller called myViewController. Then i have an NSObject called myLogic. myLogic has a method called executeLogic() which will call some delegate methods. (Im guessing the delegate methods are called in separate threads). I am calling executeLogic() from myViewController and i want it to execute all the delegate methods before returning to execute the next command on myViewController. Right now i get this error

```
 [URLRequestDBStoreLogic respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5d2cff0
```

which i am guessing is because it returns to the main thread before the delegate methods are called? I am not sure. Any solutions? Will be deeply grateful. :)

This is where the URLRequestDBStoreLogic class is called (note this is an NSObject Class)

```
  URLRequestDBStoreLogic * urlRequestLogicDBStoreLogic = [[URLRequestDBStoreLogic alloc]init];
[urlRequestLogicDBStoreLogic loadObjectsAtRemoteServer];
```

This is what the method that is called does

```
 - (void) loadObjectsAtRemoteServer {

RKURL * url = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://y.co.uk/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/search?site=&term=&tag=x&maxResults=251&sort=&query=&repo=false"];
objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
  //Some other Code
   [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"?tag=x" delegate:self];
}
```

and this is where it breaks in the if statement.

```
// Setup the NSURLRequest. The request must be prepared right before dispatching
 - (BOOL)prepareURLRequest
  {
    [_URLRequest setHTTPMethod:[self HTTPMethod]];

if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWillPrepareForSend:)]) {
    [self.delegate requestWillPrepareForSend:self];
}

}
```

Comment: Delegate methods are not executed on separate threads, except if you do so yourself.

Comment: Is URLRequestDBStoreLogic a class or an object?

Comment: Its an NSObject.. If not then why do i get this error? Its strange..

Comment: But is it a class or an instance? `respondsToSelector:` is an instance method.

Comment: You probably have to show us the salient snippets of code (e.g. where you create `myLogic` and set its delegate, the code where your code invokes the delegate's method, etc.).

Comment: Well It is an NSOBject Class but i am creating an instance of it and then calling a method.. I will post some code

Comment: Most useful will be two lines: first from the URLRequestDBStoreLogic definition and second where URLRequestDBStoreLogic object is created.

Comment: i think a sample code for the issue would be better to understand...